When storing secrets within a Key Vault (Such as 1Password Developer Tools or Azure KeyVault), how do you properly protect the keyvaults secret?
When looking to avoid keeping secrets in code (so it doesn't get checked into source control) and having them encrypted in some fashion (so they're not exposed if a machine is compromised), I'm missing something obvious here.
Azure KeyVault appears to have built in auto-authentication, but only if your app is hosted on Azure, which makes it not work for on-premise deployments.
That leaves me with one gaping hole in the security plan - I can move the handful of secrets into one of these tools, but I then somehow need to authenticate to the tool itself.
This makes it seem like it accomplishes nothing, as we've just replaced one secret with another.
What key piece am I missing here?

for azure hosted apps use key vault with managed identity and for on premises deployment use key vault with service principal authentication where these two are best practices one can follow @owen  Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview

You are not missing a key piece. Outside of the azure environment with no possibilities for using managed identities you need a service principal to access the key vault.
You can configure the azure key vault to only accept certain ips or ip ranges to narrow down access to the key vault.
